# How put Dependency Property in not Miscellaneous panel?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

When I add Dependency Property to my user control, I always finded it in Miscellaneous panel on a properties window (in Expression Blend).
But, some times i've too many custom properties and all they are in Miscellaneous panel.
How I can put properties to othe panel? May be I can make my own panel? But I do not know - how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes in [System.ComponentModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.aspx) determine this.

In your case, you need to specify the [[Category]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx) to use for your property.

Answer (score 1):

I like to additionally decorate the method with a description as such:

```
    [Category("Modal Options")]
    [Description("Set the modal background on or off")]
    public bool Modal
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ModalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModalProperty, value); toggleModal(); }
    }
```

This shows in the tool tip which is useful.