# How do I declare a DependencyProperty under the "Visibility" category instead of "Other"?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

I have a few DependencyProperties defined in some custom user controls. I'd like for Visual Studio (and Blend as a bonus) to list these properties under the "Visibility" category instead of "Other" or "Miscellaneous".

How can I add some metadata to these properties to make this happen?

**Edit:** To clarify my question, I guess I want the "normal" get/set properties to show up and not really the static Dependency Properties themselves, so as an example, the property I want to group is `ConnectorLabelText`:

```
public string ConnectorLabelText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ConnectorLabelTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ConnectorLabelTextProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ConnectorLabelText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ConnectorLabelTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ConnectorLabelText", typeof(string), typeof(InputConnector), new UIPropertyMetadata("IN"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929693/how-put-dependency-property-in-not-miscellaneous-panel) question

Adding an example

```
[Description("My Description"), Category("Visibility")]
public string ConnectorLabelText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ConnectorLabelTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ConnectorLabelTextProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: D'oh, thanks - was googling around for wrong term on this one :(

Comment: Hehe no problems :) That can easily happend